# Converting virtual address to real address - in hexadecimal

Tags: memory, operating-system, memory-address, virtual-memory, mmu

[question for converting virtual address to real address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukm47.png)

I looked through stack overflow for similar questions but I unfortunately did not know how to apply the same steps to this question, therefor I am asking again how to covert the addresses and I apologise for the repetitive question but I am kinda new and slow at this..

please refer to the link on top for the screenshot of the question and thank you in adnvance.